# Scan shallow water

Tags: radar, sonar

I need to scan a shower tray with & without the water running to assess the puddling at the drain, then export a point cloud or surface.  Sonar & Laser dont seem to be able to deliver, can radar achieve this? (Maximum size of tray is 2m x 2m, while the water can be 1mm- 10mm deep).

Looking for hardware & software.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: generally, laser and sonar can both deliver what you seem to want, radar might, too. I guess you just hope this would be easier than it is. In essence, while signal processing *is* an important aspect to this problem, you haven't done the overall engineering (or rather, you don't describe that), and I don't think this question fits overly well here.

Comment: Can you talk a little bit about the application? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Marcus, you are correct; I am looking for an off-the-shelf solution or at least a solution provider. This forum looks fairly heavy on the maths, not what i was expecting but I have to start somewhere.

Comment: Generally we measure the flow rate of gravity-fed drainage fittings with ultrasonic flow meter and height gauge within a flood tank, making a litre per minute/ head of water report.

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting enter. Within a shower environment the puddle of water you stand in is critical (the smaller the better). I want to scan the dry shower tray, then scan the 'puddle' under different flow rates; exporting a point cloud for manipulation. Looking for an off-the-shelf solution, does anyone know of water scanning specialists? Laser suppliers do not like my splashing surfaces, falling rain, glossy surfaces.  I hope this is clarification?

Comment: Look into FMCW radar applications which provide this (see https://www.process-worldwide.com/challenging-overcoming-the-limits-of-fmcw-radar-in-level-measurement-a-706471/)  Consider 60 GHz solutions since that is an unlicensed band and the small wavelength can provide significantly higher precision. The  high oxygen absorption in this band and inability to penetrate most objects is actually an advantage for such short range applications (minimizing interference from other possible transmitters).

Comment: I found one such solution: https://senz2.com/project/wireless-level-radar/, could not find a price however.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be as simple as affixing a set of depth meter sticks on the floor of the basin and using an ordinary webcam to read the levels?

If the depth meter sticks might interfere with some type of flow you are measuring, you could shine a laser plane on the surface and read the intersection line with a webcam.  See my answer for this question: [Camera and laser scanner calibration final approach questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48366)

Just some ideas, hope they inspire.

Ced